# Hide some database on server for specified user

Tags: database, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

Currently I want create user to my database that i have on sql azure service. On my server I have 5 databases and I want grant access to my new user only for one database. Currently i create login and user on master (to provide login functionally to it) and also create login in my target database. The problem that I already have is that my already created user also see other database (only names, he can't check any other information, but he shouldn't see this names). So my question is what is the valid way to create user in sql-azure database (with sql server 2017), that have only acces to one specific database, and also don't see any other databases on server ?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem that I already have is that my already created user also see other database (only names, he can't check any other information, but he shouldn't see this names)

You can create contained users .Below is some info about contained users

> In the contained database user model, the login in the master database is not present. Instead, the authentication process occurs at the user database, and the database user in the user database does not have an associated login in the master database.

User must always specify database though

> To connect as a contained database user, the connection string must always contain a parameter for the user database so that the Database Engine knows which database is responsible for managing the authentication process.

you will need to specify database from ssms dropdown

[image]